Zip input and output without wildcards, using absolute paths
Very similar to Coupling inputs and outputs without shared wildcards, I have assembled a user-specified list of inputs and outputs that are paired:
inputs = ["/path/to/input1", "/path/to/input2"]
outputs = ["/path/to/output1", "/path/to/output2"]

In other words, I have a rule which should process input1 and generate output1, and in parallel the same rule may also process input2 and generate output2. I can try the recommended answer from the linked question, which looks like this, except I have used absolute paths, and remove the ".txt" suffix from the rules:
numbers = ['/tmp/1.txt', '/tmp/2.txt', '/tmp/3.txt', '/tmp/4.txt']
letters = ['/tmp/A.txt', '/tmp/B.txt', '/tmp/C.txt', '/tmp/D.txt']

ln = dict(zip(numbers, letters))

rule all:
    input:
        expand('{number}', number= numbers),

rule out:
    input:
        letter= lambda wc: ln[wc.number],
    output:
    '{number}'
    shell:
        """
        echo {input.letter} > {output}
        """

I have tried touching the inputs /tmp/A.txt, etc., however no matter how I try to arrange it, I get either key exceptions or missing input exceptions. However, if I use relative instead of absolute paths, I can get it to work. Is there any way to get it to work using all absolute paths?

The error occurs because the '{number}' wildcard is too broad. It can match any string, leading to unexpected behavior.
...
Error:
  KeyError: '/tmp/A.txt' ## Notice here.
Wildcards:
  number=/tmp/A.txt
...

To fix this, you can use wildcard_constraints to limit the scope of the number wildcard:
numbers = ['/tmp/1.txt', '/tmp/2.txt', '/tmp/3.txt', '/tmp/4.txt']
letters = ['/tmp/A.txt', '/tmp/B.txt', '/tmp/C.txt', '/tmp/D.txt']

ln = dict(zip(numbers, letters))

wildcard_constraints:
    number="|".join(map(re.escape, numbers))

rule all:
    input:
        expand('{number}', number=numbers)

rule out:
    input:
        letter=lambda wc: ln[wc.number]
    output:
        '{number}'
    shell:
        """
        echo {input.letter} > {output}
        """

You can try below code to get a clearer error:
numbers = ['/tmp/1.txt', '/tmp/2.txt', '/tmp/3.txt', '/tmp/4.txt']
letters = ['/tmp/A.txt', '/tmp/B.txt', '/tmp/C.txt', '/tmp/D.txt']

ln = dict(zip(numbers, letters))

ln["/tmp/A.txt"] = "/tmp/1.txt"

rule all:
    input:
        expand('{number}', number= numbers),



def get_input(wc):
    print(wc)
    return ln[f"{wc.number}"]

rule outtes:
    input:
        letter= get_input,
    output:
        '{number}'
    shell:
        """
        echo {input.letter} > {output}
        """

